# Two clocks gaining and losing time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Two clocks show 8 o'clock. One clock gains 1 minute and the other loses one minute each hour. After how many hours will they show the same time again?

I tried solving this question by hit and trial like in one hour one min.
I found that at 2 o'clock there is again a probability to meet, so from 8 o'clock to 2 o'clock, it is 6 hours, which is 360 minutes, so I think that they should meet after 360 hours. But I am confused; is my answer correct?

Comment: The difference is two minutes per hour. So actually the second clock doesn't matter, it would be the same if the other clock was normal and the other gained two minutes each our.

Comment: ok thank you for hint.

Comment: I think I am confused with this being a probability question (i think its not). Wont it just be 6 hours because the clock is a $12$ hourly timeline (half $= 6$), because the change in time is the same on both losing and gaining time of the respective clocks, they will meet after {$8 + 6, 8 - 6$} $= 2$.

Comment: Also, we need to make a difference between 12 hour clock and 24 hour clock.

Comment: @SnipingPoodle: I've edited the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The goal is to determine the period between two meetings of the two clocks, given that the speed of the faster clock relative to the slower one is $2$ mins per hour. (Notice that the given starting time $8$ o'clock is arbitrary, and thus irrelevant.)

Let's assume a $12$-hour clock. So, the duration between two meetings is $12$ hours $= 720$ mins. Thus, the required period is $720$ mins $\div (2$ mins per hour$) = 360$ hours $= 15$ days.

Comment: +1 for the units in the calculation. You can even assume one of the clocks is stopped and the other is running if that helps visualize the problem.

Comment: @EthanBolker Indeed, this is a simple but good example of a problem where leveraging on dimensional analysis is helpful, but more importantly, where neglecting the units is potential trouble: 720÷2=360 makes one tempted to just carelessly assume 360 mins (=6 hours).